# If the minimal polynomial of a linear operator has distinct roots, its characteristic polynomial also will have distinct roots.

Tags: linear-algebra

If the minimal polynomial of a linear operator has distinct roots, its characteristic polynomial
also will have distinct roots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to prove it is false, with a *very* simple $2\times2$ matrix having $x$ as minimal polynomial and $x^2$ as characteristic polynomial.